# Add debounce in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This function is performed on the `onChange` action. I want only what is under the comment to debounce on 1s. How can I accomplish this?

```
  onChange = (event, { newValue }) => {
    this.setState({
      value: newValue,
    }, () => {
      if (this.state.value.length !== 26) {
// this debounce \/
        this.Auth.getUsersData(newValue).then(res => {
          if (res) {
            this.setState({
              accountBills: res,
            });
          }
        });
  };
    });
}
```

Comment: I often use underscore library to do debounce. Take a look at this link https://underscorejs.org/#debounce. You can write a function for getUser then const debounce = _.debounce(getUser, 1000); debounce()

Answer (score 1):

Just extract that code into a new method and wrap it in `_.debounce`:

```
import {debounce} from 'lodash';

getUserData = debounce(newValue => this.Auth.getUsersData(newValue)
  .then(res => {
    if (res) { this.setState({ accountBills: res }) }
   })
, 1000);

onChange = (event, { newValue }) => {
    this.setState({
      value: newValue,
    }, () => {
      if (this.state.value.length !== 26) {
         this.getUserData(newValue);
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: than u its working but I must this.getUserData(newValue); :)